# How to get the text of the label from the axis ticks using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, axis-labels

The fact is that I try to filter the ticks I'm showing on the xaxis by comparing their label to a regular expression. I'm currently "filtering" by taking only one on sixty of them. But, as I'm playing with non periodic functions while willing to emphasize a certain phenomenon, I need to be able to get the label of the tick.
In order to do that, I need to be able to put the "value" of the label in a variable. But I don't know how to get the Text. I've tried the get_text() method, but all I get is an empty String. Here is the part of my code which I think is relevant here, ask me if you think you need some precisions :

```
    for index, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
        if index % (2*30) != 0:
            label.set_visible(False)
        else:
            print(label.get_text())
    for index, tick in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklines()):
        if index % (4*30) != 0:
            tick.set_visible(False)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbjsO.png), an example using the Bitcoin value over 2 years, with the x-axis graduated every 60 days.
As I can't get the value of the label, I can't focus on the first day of each month for example.
Thanks to all the people who will read me, and if you've got an answer, please tell me!!

Comment: You need to call this at the end of your plotting (just before calling `plt.show()`), not at the start. See the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/fig_axes_customize_simple.html). If you post more of your code, people can check whether something else is preventing you from getting the labels.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found this one! It will be useful if I was one day stuck with this method. Still I found another way to do it (my answer down below), and I think it's more relevant in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact trying to get the text from the label wasn't this relevant. Because this text is the value of the x-value. So, I was basically trying to get the x-value by another way...
This is the code I came up with :

```
for index, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if re.findall(".*-.[13579]-0[2-9]", dateList[index]) or re.findall(".*-.[13579]-[123].", dateList[index]) or re.findall(".*-.[02468]-.*", dateList[index]):
        label.set_visible(False)
for index, tick in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklines()):
    if index % (4*30) != 0:
        tick.set_visible(False)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbIxi.png), illustrated with the Bitcoin value over 2 years, where the x-axis is graduated every 2 months